# laravel 7 api CSRF token mismatch on POST request

Tags: php, laravel, api

Am I right that I need just to add api/* path to exception in /app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
        'api/*',
    ];
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: are you using `routes/web.php` or `routes/api.php` ?

Comment: `routes/web.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `api.php` file for api routes, as they are not checked for csrf_token middleware by default in `app/http/kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
          ...
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
          ...
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Comment: Thank you. It must be described here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport 
I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is, you've defined your api routes on `routes/web.php`, if you want to use `/api` from your root domain then make your API routes on `routes/api.php`.

**routes/api.php** :

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Now you can access through `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test`

The `web.php` file contains routes that the **RouteServiceProvider** places in the web middleware group, which provides session state, `CSRF` protection, and cookie encryption. If your application does not offer a stateless, RESTful API, all of your routes will most likely be defined in the `web.php` file.

The `api.php` file contains routes that the **RouteServiceProvider** places in the `api` middleware group, which provides rate limiting. These routes are intended to be stateless, so requests entering the application through these routes are intended to be authenticated via tokens and will not have access to session state.

See the official documentation **[here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/structure#the-routes-directory)**